# MAC OS VENTURA - Problem to connect to any api

Tags: macos, curl, fork, guzzle, macos-ventura

I've been using the MacBook Pro Ventura for about 2 months, I work with PHP and Laravel and after switching to Ventura I'm having a problem, when I try to connect some API using Laravel's Guzzle, local or external, i get the error:

```
objc[81552]: +[__NSCFConstantString initialize] may have been in progress in another thread when fork() was called.
objc[81552]: +[__NSCFConstantString initialize] may have been in progress in another thread when fork() was called. We cannot safely call it or ignore it in the fork() child process. Crashing instead. Set a breakpoint on objc_initializeAfterForkError to debug.
```

It's not the first API communication I've done, so I'm convinced the problem is some bug related to OS Ventura. I even found some "solutions" how to add these settings in the .zshrc or .bash_profile file:

```bash
export OBJC_DISABLE_INITIALIZE_FORK_SAFETY=YES
export DISABLE_SPRING=true
export NO_PROXY=*
```

But these solutions didn't work for me. I tested it on two projects, one with PHP 8.1 and the other with 7.2, and I had the same issue on both.
Adding these settings in .zshrc or .bash_profile the error is not displayed but the request is not sent either.

I also tested it on Insomnia and Postman and both programs were able to use the API I used in the PHP codes.

I also have the Macbook with the latest version of Ventura as of this writing.

Comment: here is some interesting links https://www.wefearchange.org/2018/11/forkmacos.rst.html http://www.sealiesoftware.com/blog/archive/2017/6/5/Objective-C_and_fork_in_macOS_1013.html to check